# How do I request the addition of BitPim to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, software-center, phone, cdma

BitPim used to be included in Ubuntu's Software Center.  When I upgraded to 16.04 BitPim was removed from my system and was no longer listed in Software Center.  How can I request the return of BitPim to the Software Center?

Answer (score 1):

BitPim has been removed upstream at debian.

[Bug#808105: Removed package(s) from unstable](https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/bitpim/news/20151217T190018Z.html)

[bitpim REMOVED from testing](https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/bitpim/news/20151218T163911Z.html)

Ubuntu 16.04 uses the testing branch of debian thus if a package is removed from debian testing it is also removed from ubuntu.

You would need to go back to Ubuntu 14.04 or install BitPim manually from their homepage.